# Return type of generic function not assignable to actual return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Not sure how to make the types work. I am constraining `t` and the returned value is correct but typescript doesn't seem to be able to work that out.

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycAXMiAK4C2ARtAUTWQM5hSgDmBAvgQTBRAIwwdCGQxkAHgAqyCAA9IIACbNkAawgBPdJIzoAfAAowZGQEoyBgNoyAusgA+yQSogxQEFTgbJgkqbIALyhyADkcOEWvoREyFAQYBRQ4gCMyADUyAAsfrxxicmpPHz4CGKsxBnBEsaR0cgA9E3IzAAW6BQANj505NR0UM6uqh5ePkUp4mDaAA4QBBUgVTQ1deE0jS1tnT19KKzsIBwjbuMg3glJ08izCwRAA)

```
interface Foo {
  a: number
  b: string
}

function f <T extends keyof Foo>(t: T): Foo[T] | undefined {
  if (t === 'a') {
    return 1 + 4 // ⚠️ error here
  }
  return
}

const a1 = f('a') // should be number | undefined return type
const b1 = f('b') // should be string | undefined return type
```

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Foo[T] | undefined'
```

---

Workaround , ew

```
function f <T extends keyof Foo>(t: T): Foo[T] | undefined {
  if (t === 'a') {
    return 1 + 4 as Foo[T]
  }
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace Foo[T] to Foo[keyof Foo].
It worked for me.

```js
interface Foo {
  a: number
  b: string
};

const a = <T extends keyof Foo>(t: T): Foo[keyof Foo] | undefined => {
  if (t === 'a') {
    return 1 + 4
  };
  
  return
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. the type is not preserved for the return type `const b = a('a')` b should be a string but it's `string | number | undefined`

Comment: yeah I just noticed. I don't know what wrong conditional types docs do it the same way as here. Kindly update the question if you find a solution.

Comment: yep absolutely will do!